# Is there a way to set columns to null within dask read_sql_table?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm connecting to an oracle database and trying to bring across a table with roughly 77 million rows. At first I tried using chunksize in pandas but I always got a memory error no matter what chunksize I set. I then tried using Dask since I know its better for large amounts of data. However, there're some columns that need to be made NULL, is there away to do this within read_sql_table query like there is in pandas when you can write out your sql query?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I recommend setting this up on the oracle side, making a view with the correct data types, and using read_sql_table with that.

You *might* be able to do it directly, since read_sql_table accepts sqlalchemy expressions. If you can phrase it as such, it ought to work.